# Display template of a member in details component

Tags: content-hub, dam

Is the display template working in Content Hub v4.2?
I have a Products member with this display template but it's not showing me the desired output. I'm just getting the Product Name

```
Display template: {ProductName}-{ProductNumber}-{SKUNumber}
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have values for `ProductNumber` and `SKUNumber`?

Comment: Yes, apparently this was an issue in Content Hub and is fixed in v4.2.27 MONE-36089.

Comment: Happy to hear that it was resolved! 

Please write it in answer and close your question :)